# Seg Fault in BST inorder traversal

Tags: c, gcc

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <string.h>
#define n 5

struct node
{
    int num;
    char *symbol;
    char *code;
    struct node *left;
    struct node *right;
}*root_ptr, *current, *previous;

void form_bst_of_dividing_positions();
void inorderTraversal(struct node *);

int dividing_positions[n], counter = 0;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    //code to populate dividing_positions

    //tree structure formation
    counter = 0;
    root_ptr = malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    root_ptr->num = dividing_positions[0];
    root_ptr->code = root_ptr->symbol = NULL;
    root_ptr->left = root_ptr->right = NULL;
    form_bst_of_dividing_positions();

    inorderTraversal(root_ptr);
    return 0;
}
void form_bst_of_dividing_positions()
{
    for(i=1;i<n;i++)
    {
        if(dividing_positions[i]==-1)
            break;
        else
        {
            struct node nodeToAdd;
            nodeToAdd.num = dividing_positions[i];
            nodeToAdd.code = nodeToAdd.symbol = NULL;
            nodeToAdd.left = nodeToAdd.right = NULL;

            current = previous = root_ptr;
            while(current!=NULL)
            {
                previous = current;
                current = (dividing_positions[i]<(current->num))? current->left : current->right;
            }
            if(nodeToAdd.num<(previous->num))
                previous->left = &nodeToAdd;
            else
                previous->right = &nodeToAdd;
        }
    }
}
void inorderTraversal(struct node *no)
{
    if(no!=NULL)
    {
        inorderTraversal(no->left);
        printf("%d ", no->num);
        inorderTraversal(no->right);
    }
}
```

Above code gives me Segmentation fault .. in Codeblocks the output window prints 4 infinitely. 2, 3, 1, 4 = to be inserted into BST. Ive converted my Java code to C, are there any specifics to be handled in my above code?

Thanks..

Comment: Have you tried using a debugger?

Comment: If you build a debug version and run in a debugger, the debugger will stop at the location of the crash. The debugger will then let you examine and walk up the function call stack, so if the crash isn't in your code then you can walk up the call stack until you get to your code. There you can examine values of variables to help you understand why the crash happens. If nothing else, please edit your question to include the function call stack.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your nodeToAdd is a local variable, its address becomes invalid once you leave that code block. You should use `malloc` to create new nodes (and free them with `free` eventually).

Comment: oops yeah right .. sorry, how silly .. had lost a bit of track of C after too much Java :)

Answer (score 1):

Use malloc everytime you add a new node.